# Cannot build being Class Annotation Processor

Tags: java, maven, annotation-processing

I have a Project with the following structure:
Annotation Format

```
package io.tholv.annotation;
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Target({ElementType.FIELD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
public @interface Format {
    String pattern() default "";

    boolean trim() default false;

    boolean upperCase() default false;

    boolean lowerCase() default false;

    boolean capitalize() default false;
}
```

and class FormatProcessor :

```
package io.tholv.annotation.process;

import com.google.auto.service.AutoService;
import io.tholv.annotation.Format;

import javax.annotation.processing.*;
import javax.lang.model.SourceVersion;
import javax.lang.model.element.Element;
import javax.lang.model.element.ElementKind;
import javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement;
import javax.lang.model.element.VariableElement;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.Set;

@SupportedAnnotationTypes("io.tholv.annotation.Format")
@AutoService(Processor.class)
@SupportedSourceVersion(SourceVersion.RELEASE_8)
public class FormatProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {

    @Override
    public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {
        for (Element element : roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(Format.class)) {
            if (element.getKind() == ElementKind.FIELD) {
                VariableElement variableElement = (VariableElement) element;
                String fieldName = variableElement.getSimpleName().toString();
                Format format = variableElement.getAnnotation(Format.class);
                try {
                    Field field = variableElement.getEnclosingElement().getClass().getDeclaredField(fieldName);
                    field.setAccessible(true);
                    Object fieldValue = field.get(variableElement.getEnclosingElement());
                    if (fieldValue instanceof String) {
                        if (format.trim()) {
                            fieldValue = ((String) fieldValue).trim();
                        }
                        if (format.upperCase()) {
                            fieldValue = ((String) fieldValue).toUpperCase();
                        }
                        if (format.lowerCase()) {
                            fieldValue = ((String) fieldValue).toLowerCase();
                        }
                        if (format.capitalize()) {
                            String str = (String) fieldValue;
                            fieldValue = str.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + str.substring(1);
                        }
                        field.set(variableElement.getEnclosingElement(), fieldValue);
                        return true;
                    }else{
                        throw new RuntimeException("Field " + fieldName + " is not a String");
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

and pom.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>io.tholv</groupId>
    <artifactId>common</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.auto.service</groupId>
            <artifactId>auto-service</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <auto-service.version>1.0-rc2</auto-service.version>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-compile</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <compilerArgument>-proc:none</compilerArgument>
                            <includes>
                                <include>io/tholv/annotation/process/FormatProcessor.java</include>
                            </includes>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile-project</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

and file  META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor :

```
io.tholv.annotation.process.FormatProcessor
```

[image: struct project]

full code here  => [link](https://github.com/pudo58/common_lib)

When I build **mvn clean compile package** and it says success, but this annotation doesn't work in other Project, someone help me see where my code is wrong, thanks